# How to retrieve Product-Names from Searched results for eCommerce Site while performing Automation Testing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get the text from the searched result but it shows me "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable" and want compare it with expected result below is my code [Python+Selenium]

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time texts = []  
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\\chromedriver.exe") 
driver.maximize_window()   driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/") 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.search-keyword").send_keys("ber")  
texts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product']/h4") print(texts)
```

Here is the website: https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/
Trying to search "ber" and want to get all the product names

Thanks for your help in Advacne!

Comment: The error message explains what you should do. Your variable `proname` contains a single element, and then you try to loop over this single element, which is not supported. You probably need to loop over a set of children of `proname`.

Comment: @physicalattraction Can you please help me demo code

Comment: I have never used Selenium, so I cannot help you with the specifics. You should check what is inside your variable `proname`, e.g. by printing it out as a dictionary before looping over it: `print(proname.__dict__)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.
First of all you have to add a delay before getting the resulted elements with `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product']/h4")`
The best way to do that is to introduce an Expected Conditions explicit wait.
Also your `texts` object is a list of web elements.
You can't print it directly.
What you can do is to iterate over that list of web elements and extract a text from each web element and then print it.
The following should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time texts = []  
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\\chromedriver.exe") 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()   driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/") 
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.search-keyword")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.search-keyword").send_keys("ber")  
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product']/h4")))

text_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product']/h4")
for text_element in text_elements:
    el_text = text_elements.text
    print(el_text)
```